# Stop auto refresh

Tags: jquery

Alright, new problem with the code i've been working on; I cannot get a auto refresh  to stop when a item is clicked open, and then restart once the item is clicked close.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var auto_refresh = setInterval( function() { $('#body').load('body.php').fadeIn('slow'); }, 1000);
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.star, .ship').click(function(){
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    var linkvar = 'content.php?lid=';
                    var link_full = linkvar + name;
                    $('#box').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#box_content').addClass(type);
                    if(auto_refresh)
                    {
                        clearInterval(auto_refresh);    
                    }
                    $('#box_content').load(link_full);
                });
$('#close_this_box').click(function(){
    $('#box').addClass('hidden'); $('#box_content').empty();
    var auto_refresh = setInterval( function() { $('#body').load('body.php').fadeIn('slow'); }, 1000);
    });
$('.ship, .star').hover(
    function()
    { 
        $(this).children('div').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 
    function(){ $(this).children('div:nth-child(2)').addClass('hidden');});
});
</script>
```

It either continues to auto refresh or just doesn't load the #body div at all.

Comment: Are `.ship`, `.star`, or `#close_this_box` children of `#body`?

Comment: They're all children of #body. If you'd like i can post the HTML as well (Patrick Evan's answer 'fixed' the problem though now i'm having an issue with the refresh and stuff, so i'd be willing to post more lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `var` keyword before `auto_refresh` in the `$('#close_this_box').click(` function

```
$('#close_this_box').click(function(){
    $('#box').addClass('hidden'); $('#box_content').empty();
    auto_refresh = setInterval( function() { $('#body').load('body.php').fadeIn('slow'); }, 1000);
});
```

using `var` there makes a local variable  named `auto_refresh` instead of modifying the global variable `auto_refresh`.

Comment: that did it. And i feel like an idiot now. thank you :D

Edit: Actualy scratch that, it looked like it was working but apparently something stalled on the site.

Comment: you could also move the declaration of the `auto_refresh` variable into the `.ready` function, which will keep it visible to the event functions you have defined in it, and keep the global space clean. However it will not be visible to functions you declare outside of the `.ready` function

Comment: what do you mean something stalled?

Comment: My entire site seized up. i had to restart my browser. (nothing to do with the code; I just had one to many things running at once). The code is refreshing now, like its supposed to however once i click open either the .star or the .ship, after the timeout, the page refreshes and closes out everything.